# Splice out this.index from array between components in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an array of quotes in my parent template which I pass to a child component as a prop.  I then take that array and create another child component for each index in the array by passing it through a for loop into a slot.  This all seems to work fine.

The problem is that I am trying to delete each index of the array on clicking it's element, but whenever I click an element the first index is deleted, not the index linked to the element clicked.

In the following component I execute method @click and run the method deleteQuote passing the related index.

```
<template>
  <div class="panel-body" @click="deleteQuote">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  export default{
    methods: {
        deleteQuote() {
            this.$emit('deleteThisQuote', this.index)
        }
    },
    props: ['index']
  }
</script>
```

Since this component doesn't have direct access to my array, I emit a custom event that is listened for in its parent.  This triggers another method which splices my array at this.index.  Following is the parent component...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <quote-singles 
        class="col-sm-3 panel panel-default" 
        v-for="(quote, index) in quotes"
        :index="index"
        @deleteThisQuote="deleteQuote($event)"><h3>{{index}}{{quote}}</h3>
    </quote-singles>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
  import quoteSingles from './quoteSingles.vue'

  export default{
    methods: {
        deleteQuote(event) {
            this.quotes.splice(this.event, 1);
        }
    },
    props: ['quotes'],
    components: {
        'quoteSingles': quoteSingles
    }
  }
</script>
```

This does everything I want, except it splices out the wrong index in the array.  No matter which element I click, myArray[0] is removed.  What is going on here?  Am i missing something elementary?

Comment: this.event is not in the array. You set it up to use the event psrsmeter, not this.event  - you would the use +event.target.getAttribute('index')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 methods: {
   deleteQuote(event) {
     this.quotes.splice(this.event, 1);
   }
 }
```

You are passing "event" and then trying to splice this.event.
Since you already have access to the index, just pass index instead of $event

```
 @deleteThisQuote="deleteQuote(index)"
```

The method would look like the following:

```
 methods: {
   deleteQuote(index) {
     this.quotes.splice(index, 1)
   }
 }
```

Comment: I plugged in your method and I am now getting the behavior that it deletes the last index in the array each click.  Any idea why?  (have an upvote)

Comment: Just seen another thing in your code, I will edit my answer.